# Node Server Express Error 404 Not Found app.get()

Tags: node.js, express

This is the route i have in my server `app.get('/coolPath', function (req, res) {}`

When I run in on my local it works fine, once I upload it to the server. It gives me 404 File or directory not found. My application is listening to the correct port. Should I do some adjustments on the IIS?

Comment: IIS???? nodejs doesn't run in IIS, it need only nodejs installed. How are you deploying your app?

Comment: NodeJs is installed. Just copied the whole directory to the server.

Comment: @Tony put some code bro

Comment: Can you update you question with your complete `server.js` file, and your `package.json`. If you have a any deployment script can you add that as well?

Comment: here is my server.js file. https://gist.github.com/tmamedbekov/0814c274e1d4683e88b87cb53bac2978

Answer (score 0):

Have you started your application on the server? You must run:

```
npm start
```

from command line in the folder where your app is deployed.

Answer (score -1):

Are you referring to any file in your get code? Can you please give us the complete code which you have written in app.get('coolPath')..

Maybe you are referring some file in the code which doesn't exists and that's why you are getting the error.

Comment: This is not an answer, but merely a comment.